# Deep network accuracy collapses after reaching a peak value

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to build a deep network using TF after using Martin Gorner's video as a reference. I has some success with the shallow network example; however the deep network's accuracy is collapsing after reaching around 98% accuracy for some reason.

The network implemented is used to recognise MNIST numerical characters using a five layer network. I am training with batches of 100 for 10000 iterations. The accuracy steadily increases until it reaches around 98%, then collapses completely to 9.8%.

Any ideas please?

```
"""Tensor flow character recognition of Numerals"""
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data", one_hot=True)

# layer K will have 200 neuron and so on
K = 200
L = 100
M = 60
N = 30

# ----- Initialization -----
# the None will become the batch size of 100
# 28 by 28 grayscale images described by a single byte
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])

# training will require computing variables W and b

W1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([28*28, K], stddev=0.1))
B1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([K]))

W2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([K, L], stddev=0.1))
B2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([L]))

W3 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([L, M], stddev=0.1))
B3 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([M]))

W4 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([M, N], stddev=0.1))
B4 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([N]))

W5 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([N, 10], stddev=0.1))
B5 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

# ----- Model -----
# the model Y = WX+b
# reshape is used to flatted the image into a 1D array of 784 locations
# -1 is used to tell python to figure the reshape as there's only  on solution
#Y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(tf.reshape(X, [-1, 784]), W) + b)

Y1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(X, W1) + B1)

Y2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(Y1, W2) + B2)

Y3 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(Y2, W3) + B3)

Y4 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(Y3, W4) + B4)

Y5 = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(Y4, W5) + B5)


# placeholder for correct answers
# e.g. correct answer for 2 will be  [0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ]
Y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])

# the loss function
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_sum(Y_ * tf.log(Y5)) * -1

# ----- Success Metrics -----
# calculate the % of correct answers found in batch
is_correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(Y5, 1), tf.argmax(Y_, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(is_correct, tf.float32))

# ----- Training Step -----
# pick an optimizer and tell it to minimize the cross entropy loss function
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.003)
train_step = optimizer.minimize(cross_entropy)

# create the execution  session
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

for i in range(10000):
    # load a batch of images from mnist
    batch_X, batch_Y = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
    train_data = {X: batch_X, Y_: batch_Y}

    # ----- Execution -----
    # train
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict=train_data)
    # test for success
    a, c = sess.run([accuracy, cross_entropy], feed_dict=train_data)

    # this is only to display information
    if i%100 == 0:

        # check for success on whole data set
        test_data = {X: mnist.test.images, Y_:mnist.test.labels}
        a, c = sess.run([accuracy, cross_entropy], feed_dict=test_data)

        print(a)
```

Comment: One thing is to check what happens to the weights: do they iterate to near zero or to near infinity?

Comment: Thanks will check. Actually I had better resulte when I changed the activation function from relu to relu6. Will check what is different as well,

Answer (score 0):

It is the accuracy on the validation set which collapses. right ?

so, you may be dramatically overfitting.
98% is possibly the best you can achieve with a network with such a capacity/structure.